# Regex to Ignore comments in Latex

Tags: regex, latex

I'm using a spell checker to improve my Latex document. I'm using vscode, and the Spell Right extension does the job. I want to have it ignore the single-line comments, so I set the following value:

```
"spellright.ignoreRegExps": [
    "%.*"
]
```

in the settings, and I expect the regex to grasp a line from the '%' forward to the end of the line. 
But the Spell Right extension considers the `%.*` Malformed. Is it really?

When I try this regex at regex101 website, it selects what I expect.

Is there another correct way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found in the Web some examples of *ignoreRegExps*, where:

- the content of regex is **surrounded with slashes**,
- after the final slash there can be **regex options** (in your case probably
  not needed).

So maybe you should change your regex to:

```
"/%.*/"
```